# Solving bitwise XOR and ROR equation

Tags: c, xor

I have been told that `x ^ ROR(x, 13) = 0x936f2a8247534566`

`^` is the XOR operator, like in C, and `ROR()` is a function that *rotates-right* the bits of the input by the specified number of positions, like the [Intel processor instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_273.html).

The question is how do I find `x`. It seems a lot of possibilities to try every 64-bit combination, maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Is `ROR` a circular shift? And how many bits is x?

Comment: Updated the question to clarify.

Comment: @Olaf I don't think this hint can help here..

Comment: Gonna be a lot of possible answers.  `1 ^ 0 == 0 ^ 1` and `0 ^ 0 == 1 ^ 1`  This means that every possible bit has 2 states that can be a solution bit for x.  Unless the rotate portion makes this impossible, which I am not seeing at the moment.

Comment: I have a solution for you, it will take time to write the answer

Comment: Is there any way to show that ROR (and ROL) is distributive on xor? Intuitively it seems like it wouldn't be.

Comment: I suspect the answer involves `0x936f2a8247534566 ^ ROR(0x936f2a8247534566, 13)` or `0x936f2a8247534566 ^ ROL(0x936f2a8247534566, 13)`.

Comment: Thats a curious question, however analyzing the problem in a simplier scenario with 6-bits like `111000 ^ ROR(111000, 3)`, `101010 ^ ROR(101010, 3)` and `010101 ^ ROR(010101, 3)`, you will see all those 3 presented values for "x" will result in `111111`, determining the correct `x` from `111111` seems ilogical, its like division by zero. This is a lossy operation where multiple inputs can have the same output. You probably can find a value for `x` that will result in `0x936f2a8247534566`, however it will certainly not be the *only* value for `x` that will result in `0x936f2a8247534566`.

Comment: @Barmar I have tried these but after testing the answer was not right.

Comment: @Havenard I suspect that the bit pattern of 0x936f2a8247534566 constrains the possible results. FYI, it's `1001001101101111001010101000001001000111010100110100100000000000`

Comment: @Barmar: no, it isn't. `66` at the end means it should end in `01100110` and not in a series of zeroes.

Comment: Its `1001001101101111001010101000001001000111010100110100010101100110`.

Comment: Oops, I used Javascript `0x936f2a8247534566.toString(2)`, but forgot that JS integers are limited to 53 bit precision.

Comment: I think this might be better for math.stackexchange.com, or maybe a puzzle site. It's not really a programming question, unless you're going to write a program in C to solve it. In which case, the OP needs to post his code so we can tell him what his bugs are.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about binary math or puzzles, not computer programming.

Comment: Some excel work leads to 2 solutions: "0001001100110111101100110011111111011110101011011011000000001011
" and "1110110011001000010011001100000000100001010100100100111111110100"  (Oops on first posts as that was the shifted value)

Comment: @Barmar: I agree. Let's close it, before we get too deep into it :-) (no pun intended)

Comment: @chux: what do you refer to? My hint was missleading, as I did accidentally used `x` which was not related to `x` in the question. It was just a (too) general hint. I just removed it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This algorithm

```
unsigned long long res = 0;
int bit = 1;
for (int k = 0, shift = 0; k < 64; k++, shift = (shift + 13) % 64)
{
    if (bit)
        res |= 1ull << shift;
    if (0x936f2a8247534566 & (1ull << shift))
        bit = 1 - bit;
}
```

gives the answer

```
0x1337b33fdeadb00b
```

And if we start start with `bit = 0`, the answer is

```
0xecc84cc021524ff4
```

---

The idea is the following. If the last bit of `0x936f2a8247534566` is `0`, it means that `bit[13] ^ bit[0] == 0`, hence bits are equal. Otherwise `bit[0]` and `bit[13]` are different.

The same logic applies to `bit[13]` and `bit[26]`, etc. So basically the number `0x936f2a8247534566` tells us which bits of the original number are equal to each other and which are not.

Since with step `13` we get all possible positions between `0` and `63`(inclusive), we need just one loop.

Comment: Thanks, is there any explanation to accompany your solution?

Comment: Note: 2 solutions are complements of each other.

Comment: "leet beef dead boob"

Comment: Note2: Method does depend on `64 % 13 != 0`, else not all bit positions would get set.

Comment: @chux I think it is rather `64` and `13` are [Coprime integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers).

Comment: @AlexD Suspect you are correct: coprime is a better dependency statement.